# How can get access to field's data of plugin block in twig template?

Tags: theming, 8, entities, blocks

how can I get access to fields data (Variables) of custom plugin block in twig template?
this block has been created by a module (Not a custom block type) and has its own twig template.
in below is shown structure of my module directory:

```
my_module
  ├ src
  | └ Plugin
  |    └ Block
  |       └ MyBlock.php
  ├ templates
  |  └ block--my-module.html.twig
  ├ my_module.info.yml
  └ my_module.module
```

MyBlock.php:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_modules\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;


/**
 * @Block(
 *   id = "my_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("My Block"),
 *   category = @Translation("My Block")
 * )
 */
class MyBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Add a form field to the existing block configuration form.

  $form['block_LinkA_url'] = array(
    '#type' => 'url',
    '#title' => t('Link A:'),
    '#size' => 60,
  );
  $form['block_LinkB_url'] = array(
    '#type' => 'url',
    '#title' => t('Link B:'),
    '#size' => 60,
  );
    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Save our custom settings when the form is submitted.
    $this->configuration['LinkA_url'] = $form_state->getValue('block_LinkA_url');
    $this->configuration['LinkB_url'] = $form_state->getValue('block_LinkB_url');
  }

}
```

I'm trying to get access to for eg `LinkA_url` Variable in `block--my-module.html.twig` with something like below code:

```
<div>
    {% block content %}
      {{ content.LinkA_url.value }}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

But whatsoever I try nothing could not be displayed , I would be happy to hear what the problem is.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use markup render arrays like this:

```
 public function build() {
    $build = [];

    $build['LinkA_url'] = ['#markup' => $this->configuration['LinkA_url']];
    $build['LinkB_url'] = ['#markup' => $this->configuration['LinkB_url']];

    return $build;
  }
```

Then in your twig:

```
  <p><a href="{{ content.LinkA_url }}">link 1</a></p>
  <p><a href="{{ content.LinkB_url }}">link 2</a></p>
```

then add hook_theme in your .module file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function my_module_theme() {
  return array(
    'block__my_module' => array(
      'base hook' => 'block'
    ),
  );
}
```

Otherwise, it won't look in your module's templates folder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I get this error message:`The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
ParseError: syntax error, unexpected`

Comment: the new array syntax works with PHP 5.4 and greater, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: I have updated the answer to remove new bracket array syntax.

Comment: Thanks again, all part of that  posted in question, I think the problem goes back to the `return array`, see this post: [Render link elements in blocks](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217395/render-link-elements-in-blocks)

Comment: I have tested locally and got it working, see revised answer.